# How to check multiple values in a matrix

Tags: nunit

I have an IO class that imports large quantity of data into a 2D array, for example int[,].  The operation can sometimes be slow.  To check the correctness of the implementation, I spot check a few columns and rows in the matrix.  The checks are grouped and should be run together for the sake of efficiency.  I am not aware of a multiple assert feature in Nunit.  A solution on SOF suggests a try-catch wrap around each of the arguments in `Assert.All(() => ..., () => ..., ...);` I prefer not to use this because the try/catch's are unnecessary and the test is verbose.

Does anyone have a better idea?  Extending the framework is fine, but keeping the local version and community version in sync is cumbersome.

Comment: What does *should be run together* mean? Do you want to have in a single statement for readadbility (I'd doubt that)? Or do you want all assertions to be done before reporting is done, so this will yield multiple fails? Or do you expect some kind of multi-threading to be done?

Comment: All assertions within some scope to be done first before reporting is kicked off.

Answer (score 0):

Use FluentAssertion's AssertionScope.